# (Manually) Approving a kext extension through Terminal in Mac OS Ventura

Tags: macos, terminal, audio, security, kernel-extensions

so I would like to keep the security settings on Mac OS Ventura enabled but also enable an audio driver for my sound card that would need to otherwise have the security settings turned off in recovery mode.

Now I recently manually approved a kext for another audio program using the kext consent command. This was done with a TEAM ID added at the end of the command. How do I find what the team ID is for Antelope Audio ( the manufacturer of my sound card).

Is there any other way of it loading the kext apart from disabling the security settings in recovery mode?

Thank you and excuse me if this is a noobish question. I have no background in programming